# Objective-C code analysis

Tags: objective-c, c, objective-c-runtime, llvm-clang

I want to write a tool that does code-completion for objective-c class-names, selector-names and property names, as the software is being developed. (ie something that can run periodically and build a tree of class names, and their properties/selectors).

Is there an API I can use for this?. . . I'm looking at clang static analyzer, but from running quickly over the docs, it seems that I need something more low level.

Comment: Build time?  You mean you want a CLANG extension that... Writes code for us during a build?

Comment: @CodaFi - heh - sorry. I described that badly. . I meant during development time.

Comment: Then the CLANG AST is the way to go.  Really, nothing you could write single-handedly could ever match the quality and breadth of the CLANG team's efforts, so may as well use it.

Comment: Wait... doesn't Xcode already do this?

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, but the APIs to support this are still private. (This is for a language-extension/tool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too many answers for this, but based on comments by @CodaFi:

Then the CLANG AST is the way to go. Really, nothing you could write single-handedly could ever match the quality and breadth of the CLANG team's efforts, so may as well use it.

Answer (score -1):

That is a truly *huge* undertaking. Does Eclipse do something like what you want? Adding that for Objective C is perhaps an attainable goal...

Comment: Thanks, but no.Eclipse is not what I'm looking for. The two options seem to be using clangs AST, or feeding in an objective-c grammar to a compilier-compiler like YACC.